# Gorilla Mux Regex for url is not matching the full url

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

What regex should I use to match the following url as the full_path?

> https://edition.cnn.com/search\?q\=test\&size\=10\&category\=us,politics,world,opinion,health

The `(?:www.|http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/).*}` does not work it matches only `www.` and up until search

```
    sm := mux.NewRouter()
    sm.HandleFunc("/", getIndex).Methods("GET")
    sm.HandleFunc(`/api/v1/hostname/{full_path:(?:www.|http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/).*}`, URLHandler)
```

Update the Handler is:

```
func URLHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    url := vars["full_path"]

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Full path is: ", url)
}
```

EDIT2:

This worked for me

```
sm := mux.NewRouter().SkipClean(true).UseEncodedPath()
sm.HandleFunc("/", getIndex).Methods("GET")
sm.HandleFunc(`/api/v1/hostname/{full_path:.+`, URLHandler)
```

And on the handler I used `url.PathUnescape(r.URL.RequestURI())` and  [xurls](https://github.com/mvdan/xurls) to extract the url

```
func URLHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    URL, _ := url.PathUnescape(r.URL.RequestURI())
    ext := xurls.Strict().FindAllString(URL, -1)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Full path is: ", ext)
}
```

Comment: The URL is a path component. That means it'll be full of escape characters, and any regex you write has to match with escape characters. As an alternative, you can simply use {full_path} in the path and parse the URL yourself to make sure it is valid.

Comment: i tried the {full_path} but it doesnt output anything

Comment: How? Show the handler code. Also, show how you're calling it

Comment: I added the handler

Comment: How are you registering the path? and how are you calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think gorilla mux will only use the path part and not the query string of the URL. Try to append `RawQuery`.

Something like this:

```golang
func URLHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    url := vars["full_path"] + "?" 
    if r.URL.RawQuery != "" {
        url += "?" + r.URL.RawQuery
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Full url is: ", url)
}
```